# Запись неизвестного кол-ва json в файл

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Есть такой код:

```
class CheckPoints
{
    public CheckPoint_Information CheckPoint_Info { get; set; }
}
class CheckPoint_Information
{
    public float Position_x { get; set; }
    public float Position_y { get; set; }
    public float Position_z { get; set; }
    public float Car_Speed { get; set; }
    public float Car_Rotation { get; set; }

}



   CheckPoints check = new CheckPoints();

    public void Write_CheckPoint(String JSON)
    {
        check.CheckPoint_Info = new CheckPoint_Information()
        {
            Car_Rotation = 1f
        };


        string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(check);
        try{
        using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\Checkpoints.json", true))
        {
            SW.WriteLine(serialized);
        }

    }
```

На выходе получается такой текст в файле:

```
{"CheckPoint_Info":{"Position_x":0.0,"Position_y":0.0,"Position_z":0.0,"Car_Speed":0.0,"Car_Rotation":1.0}}
{"CheckPoint_Info":{"Position_x":0.0,"Position_y":0.0,"Position_z":0.0,"Car_Speed":0.0,"Car_Rotation":1.0}}
{"CheckPoint_Info":{"Position_x":0.0,"Position_y":0.0,"Position_z":0.0,"Car_Speed":0.0,"Car_Rotation":1.0}}
```

Короче, получается всякая неразбериха.

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было записать в массив JSON неизвестное кол-во строк, дабы потом это можно было прочитать?

Типа такого:

```
"CheckPoints":[
{

"x":123123,
"y":321321,
"z":321132
},

{

"x":222,
"y":333,
"z":444
},

//и т.д, неизвестно, сколько таких столбцов будет

]
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: вам нужно что-бы читал человек или машина?

Comment: @Monomax, C#, машина) Я имею ввиду, чтобы можно было записать этот JSON, а затем прочитать без проблем

Comment: а записываете регулярно, или за один раз? И почему вам не сериализовать массив ваших CheckPoints?

Comment: @Monomax, записывать нужно регулярно, где-то раз в секунду

Comment: у вас на каждую новую строку уже получается отдельный CheckPoint, при ваших условиях задачи, при чтении считывать по одной линии из файла и затем десериализовать, либо набирать CheckPoint массив пока считывается массив из файла, затем добавлять к считанному массиву из файла массив новых точек, и переписывать файл заново (при этом набирая новый массив для записи). Судя по всему вам нужно несколько потоков.

Comment: Json (как и xml) обязан иметь _один_ корневой элемент. Вы в данном случае каждой записью создаете новые корневые элементы - получается невалидный json. Решение: отказаться от json. Можно использовать csv; можно использовать базу данных. Другое решение: считывать точно так же, как вы записываете: построчно из файла, каждую строку десериализовывать отдельно (как предложил Monomax).

Comment: а почему вы решили использовать для это json,  а почему не использовать xml?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `CheckPointInformation` записать в `List` сериализуйте `CheckPointStorage`

```
class CheckPointStorage
{
    public List<CheckPointInformation> CheckPoints { get; set; }
}

class CheckPointInformation
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }
    public float CarSpeed { get; set; }
    public float CarRotation { get; set; }
}
```

Также можно поменять название какого-либо свойство используя `JsonPropertyAttribute`

```
class CheckPointInformation
{
    [JsonProperty("PointX")]
    public float X { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PointX")]
    public float Y { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PointZ")]
    public float Z { get; set; }
    public float CarSpeed { get; set; }
    public float CarRotation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `записывать нужно регулярно, где-то раз в секунду` автору скорее дописывать надо данные в файл, а не просто сериализовать.

Comment: Тогда ему нужен не json, а скорее csv формат, для записи координат

Comment: это ему и посоветовали в комментах )